# How do I stop an InputFormTextBox from becoming read only when using an UpdatePanel?

Tags: rich-text, updatepanel, inputformtextbox

I'm using update panels within a SharePoint 2010 form - I know update panels aren't the best thing to be using in the first place, but time is a issue on our project - and after a user triggers a second update the rich text box is becoming read only.  The control doesn't allow me to enter text when I click on it and it doesn't display the cursor.  I can get around it by selecting a item from the toolbar, but I'm not sure why that works.

In the past, I had issues with the update panel leaving HTML tags after a single update.  I've resolved this issue by following [this page](http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/SharePoint/Richtext-contol-is-not-working-inside-updatepanel.aspx).  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this issue.

add following lines 2 lines after line "RTE_TextAreaWindow_OnLoad(richtextContolId)";

> RTE_GiveEditorFirstFocus(richtextContolId);
>   RTE_TransferIFrameContentsToTextArea(richtextContolId);

Please let me know if it helps you...:)

Cheers,
Yogesh Ghare

Answer (score 2):

To completely understand the above answer, you would require the following reference:
http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/SharePoint/Richtext-contol-is-not-working-inside-updatepanel.aspx

As suggested above, adding the following two lines after "RTE_TextAreaWindow_OnLoad(richtextContolId)", solved my problem:

```
RTE_GiveEditorFirstFocus(richtextContolId);
RTE_TransferIFrameContentsToTextArea(richtextContolId);
```